# Can I install my old laptop's CPU in a new laptop?

Tags: laptop, cpu

My current laptop is broken, but the CPU is fine (Intel Core i7-720QM, 1.6 GHz).

Can I buy a new laptop and put this CPU in it ?

Comment: Can you more clearly specify what you're trying to achieve? See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

You technically can, but it's just not a good idea.

The i7-720QM uses [Socket G1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G1). A laptop with Socket G1 is going to be hard to find these days—modern laptops with socketed processors use the incompatible [Socket G3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Socket_G3). Besides, the Haswell processors in today's laptops are a lot faster and more efficient than the Nehalem processor you have, so don't bother.

We may be able to help you better if you can tell us why you want to reuse the old processor. It really doesn't make a lot of sense to do this. (Are you intending to connect your old hard drive instead? If this is the case, get a 2.5-inch hard drive enclosure instead.)

Comment: Of course the G1 and G3 socket products cannot be used interchangeably meaning he would be buying a new laptop anyways at that point.

Comment: My guess is he doesn't want to waste his $350 CPU.

Comment: First, you find a laptop with a socket and chipset exactly like yours that is certified to have a dead cpu... Once you've passed that hurdle, then yes, you can. You may end up spending more than just getting a new laptop. Laptops are throw-away devices. Buy the peripherals when you buy the machine. They often won't be available 3-6 months after purchase.